# Send TriggeredSend with data from DataExtension

Tags: soap-api, php, fuel-sdk, dataextensions

I currently have:

1. DataExtension
2. TriggeredSend
3. E-Mail template
4. All Subscriber List

---

What I now want to do is the following: I want to send a TriggeredSend and insert data into the E-Mail from the DataExtension. So let's say, that I have the data

`Email hash: b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452`

I want that hash to appear in the TriggeredSend-Email. When editing an E-Mailtemplate I can only insert data from the All Subscrber List. However, I want to also insert data from the DataExtension into the E-Mail.

How would I do that? This has to be done without using the AllSubscriberList, because the user will only be added to that list, when he confirms the email by clicking on a link that I want to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use AMPScript in your email to retrieve the data from the Data Extension at send time.  I have several examples [here on my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

Here's the one that's most similar to your scenario:

```
%%[
var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("DataExtensionName", "ReturnColumn", "LookupColumn", @lookupValue)

]%%
DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%
```

EDIT: Lookup multiple columns:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = "whee"

set @rows = LookupRows("DataExtensionName","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row #1 */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but, there is one problem I see here: When I'm seding a TriggeredSend, I want to get a column from the DataExtension. I see how I would achieve that with your sample code. However, how exactly would I filter it? For example: I have 2 columns. E-Mail, and E-Mailhash. Filled with the data `test@example.com` and `bla@example.com`. Now, I want to get the hash for the Email address to which I'm sending the Email. How would I do that? I can see in your code how I would get a specific column, but how would I get the value of the column for the current email recipeint?

Comment: I updated my answer with another example from my blog post.

Comment: Hi. The original answer was already enough information, thanks for that! :) What I mean is, that I need the lookupValue to be the Emailaddress that the TriggeredSend will be sent too. I hope you understand what I mean. I found several links

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/

but they only describe how to set a Subscriber, and not how to retrieve the current receipeint for the email. Do you understand what I mean? I hope so. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I just had to exchange the lookupValue with `EmailAddress` and it worked! Thank you very much

Comment: There is a set of personalization strings that are available in all sends: http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/